# Is there a way to add information on fields of a class?

Tags: java, class, object, addition, difference

I have this model that has different variable inside(String, Date, Integer), some of them are other nested object.
I need to find the differences between two instance of this model and mark them(the type of marking is important, but the marks are three:

- Value of variable changed
- Value of variable before was null and now is defined
- Value has been erased

The problem is that I cannot change the model used, because is very complex, and is attached to JPA( I was thinking of change the type of any variable in some kind of markable object).
Neither is possible to produce only set of Modified, Added, Removed value, the output must preserve the object structure, because after that it should be printed in an .xlsx file, with some custom manipulation on the data.
So, my question is:"Is there a way to add information on fields of a class?" or maybe a different approach to handle this diff-marking problem?

Comment: If you are using JPA, the persistence provider will already track which changes are done to an objects that is tracked in the context/session. This looks like an XY-Problem. What is it that you really try to achieve here?

Comment: you can add variables to your entity class by annotating them as `@transient`. This way they will be ignored by JPA.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to add information on (the) fields of a class?

No, there isn't.  What you want to do is generally called logging.  Most databases, as an example, create a log of all the database changes.

Let's take a simple example.  Let's say we have a `Person` class.

```
Person
------
Person ID
Person Name
Person Address
```

And we want to monitor changes to the name or address.

We do this with an additional class.  Let's call it `PersonChanges`.

```
PersonChanges
-------------
PersonChanges ID
Person ID
PersonChanges Field (Name or Address)
PersonChanges Before
PersonChanges After
PersonChanges Timestamp
PersonChanges Who Made The Change
```

For an insert, the before field is blank or null.  For a delete, the after field is blank or null.  The timestamp allows you to see when the change was made.  The person that made the change is also usually recorded, so you can see who made an unauthorized change.

You monitor changes by creating a logging system on top of the existing system.  You have to find every instance of a model change in your application and add code to log the change.